# PhpStorm - errors from environment-based path

Tags: php, phpstorm

How can I tell PhpStorm the value for a particular environment variable so that I can still have the path-checking on and not get errors.

I'm on Windows, I have a local vagrant (debian-based) image for local testing. The code looks like:

```
define('APP_PATH', getenv('APP_ROOT').'/src/');
```

The vagrant box has its environment variables for `APP_ROOT` and the app works fine, but on Windows, where PhpStorm is running, I get errors anytime I use a require that uses `APP_ROOT` (which is numerous places). It's difficult to separate what are real errors and what are these false positives.

I've tried to set a Windows environment variable and restarting PhpStorm, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: As far as I'm aware -- there is no solution for such approach due to 1) dynamic nature of such variables and 2) no functionality to define such dynamic values. With that in mind -- the best  can suggest is to disable inspections that throw warnings on include/require statements. P.S. The only other possible alternative I can think of right now ... is to find plugin that can provide such resolution (e.g. maybe Laravel or Sumfony support plugins can do it??)